SAMBA Shares Ubuntu 22
I have a couple directories in Ubuntu that show SAMBASHARE as their group in ownership/permissions, but these same directories are not in my SMB.CONF file. Can someone tell me what is happening here?
I would actually like to add these directories as SAMBA shares but curious as to why they are already part of sambashare group.
Thank you for your assistance

Edit your question and add more information about your computer. Is it a desktop, a server, a cloud instance, or an IoT? Are you running Ubuntu 22.04 desktop or server or Core 22 for an IoT device? What are the full path of these directories? What are the ownership and permissions for these directories? Who created them? Add the contents of the smb.conf in your question and format it as code using the {_} icon above the edit window.

The only directory I know of that has sambashare as group owner - by default - is /var/lib/samba/usershares.
There are two ways to create samba shares in Ubuntu:
One is through smb.conf.
The other is through Nautilus > Local Network Share and it's this one that places share definition files at /var/lib/samba/usershares
A Samba usershare allows an ordinary user the ability to create a share of something he owns but only if that user is a member of the sambashare group. If you look at the permissions of the usershares folder it does just that.
To my knowledge that is the only use of that group.
Doesn't prohibit anyone from using that group for other purposes however.
